# How to remove text between chosen characters, strings Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

How to remove a text between chosen characters/strings in cell in google sheets? For example I have cell

XtextXu

I want to remove text between X and Xu but string "Xu" has to be a string, not just a character "X" because for example string can look like:

XtextXustringstringX and I just want to remove "text" from that cell.

I couldn't make a function

Answer (score 0):

To remove text between specific characters/strings in a cell in Google Sheets, you can use a combination of string functions such as SUBSTITUTE, MID, and SEARCH. Here's an example formula that achieves the desired result:

> =SUBSTITUTE(A1, MID(A1, SEARCH("X", A1) + 1, SEARCH("Xu", A1) - SEARCH("X", A1) - 1), "")

Assuming your cell with the text is in cell A1, this formula will remove the text between "X" and "Xu" (inclusive). It searches for the positions of "X" and "Xu" using the SEARCH function, then uses the MID function to extract the text between them. Finally, the SUBSTITUTE function replaces the extracted text with an empty string, effectively removing it.

Here's a breakdown of the formula:

1.

> SEARCH("X", A1)

- Returns the position of the first occurrence of "X" in the cell A1.

2. 

> SEARCH("Xu", A1)

- Returns the position of the first occurrence of "Xu" in the cell A1.

3. 

> MID(A1, SEARCH("X", A1) + 1, SEARCH("Xu", A1) - SEARCH("X", A1) - 1)

- Extracts the text between "X" and "Xu" using the positions obtained in steps 1 and 2.

4. 

> SUBSTITUTE(A1, MID(A1, SEARCH("X", A1) + 1, SEARCH("Xu", A1) -
> SEARCH("X", A1) - 1), "")

- Replaces the extracted text with an empty string, effectively removing it from the original cell value.

Answer (score 0):

Doable with REGEXREPLACE in one formula; with 'XtextXustringstringX' in A1 try the following:

```
=regexreplace(A1,"(X).+(Xu.*)","$1$2")
```

We are searching for an X (capture group $1), a string of any length (not captured) then Xu plus any other length of string to its right (capture group $2), then simply concatenating capture groups $1 & $2 together to get the desired result.